# cmake interrupt OpenCV building with CUDA support without error

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile opencv with CUDA 8.0 support (I compiled it successfully without CUDA). Since I need only `cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA` and `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF`, I disabled most of the modules.

This is my cmake configuration:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               3.2.0-168-g47ae5f1
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     3.2.0-55-g8b74484-dirty
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2017-02-16T10:10:04Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.5.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RelWithDebInfo
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pango-1.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 fontconfig freetype gthread-2.0 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg dl m pthread rt cudart nppc nppi npps cublas cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libjpeg libwebp libtiff libjasper IlmImf
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect xobjdetect features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo xfeatures2d
--     Disabled:                    photo stitching superres ts videostab world aruco bgsegm bioinspired ccalib contrib_world datasets dnn dpm face freetype fuzzy line_descriptor matlab optflow phase_unwrapping plot reg rgbd saliency stereo structured_light surface_matching text tracking ximgproc xphoto
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java python2 python3 viz cnn_3dobj cvv hdf sfm
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.30)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.1)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            OpenMP
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.92)
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  YES
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 30 35 37 50 52 60 61
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
--     Use fast math:               YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/mex
--     Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       NO
--     Performance tests:           NO
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/parallelOpenCV
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/opencv/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
```

However, if I run `make` or `make install` it stops the process at `100%` (without install anything). This is the output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_cudalegacy
[ 97%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/bm.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/gmg.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/interpolate_frames.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/calib3d.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/image_pyramid.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/bm_fast.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/graphcuts.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/NCV.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/needle_map.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/src/fgd.cpp.o
[ 99%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so
[ 99%] Built target opencv_cudalegacy
[ 99%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudaobjdetect/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_lbp.cu.o
[ 99%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_tvl1flow.cu.o
[ 99%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_pyrlk.cu.o
[ 99%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_farneback.cu.o
[ 99%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudaobjdetect/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_hog.cu.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_cudaobjdetect
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/cudaobjdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaobjdetect.dir/src/cascadeclassifier.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/cudaobjdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaobjdetect.dir/src/hog.cpp.o
[ 99%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so
[ 99%] Built target opencv_cudaobjdetect
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_cudaoptflow
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaoptflow.dir/src/tvl1flow.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaoptflow.dir/src/farneback.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaoptflow.dir/src/brox.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaoptflow.dir/src/pyrlk.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so
[100%] Built target opencv_cudaoptflow
```

And then it suddenly finish it, without install nothing! And if I run `make` or `make install` again, it starts from the scratch again. Notice this doesn't happens without CUDA.

Why this happens?

Comment: You probably turned off too much stuff. OpenCV's build scripts have a few bugs when you're only building a minimal amount, which sometimes leads to it just failing to do anything. Consider experimenting with enabling more stuff to see if it has the desired effect (I had a similar problem on one occasion when trying to build just opencv_core - now fixed)

Answer (score 0):

cmake had problems to install the built libraries because I didn't delete the previous objects in the install location. The problem was solved once I manually removed them (even thought I believed `make install` could have overwritten them).